# How to append a variable in to the output file's name in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have a C++ project which output data in to a file. The following is the code for it.

```
case 3:
            {
                outfile.open("price-change.csv");
                if(! outfile)
                {
                    cout << "Can not open outfile" << endl;
                    exit(1);
                }
```

i want to mutate the file name as `price-change-2014-12-23` where `2014-12-23` is a variable added to the file name, price change. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have existing file, that you work with, first you should rename it using `std::rename`, and then work with it.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string filename = "price-change-" + datestring + ".csv"
outfile.open(filename);
```

Should do it.

Thomas Matthews points out in the comments that older compilers and compilers without C++11 support enabled the file must be opened with a `const char *` rather than a `std::string`. If the above produces an error message and C++11 cannot be used, open the file with

```
outfile.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: Some versions of C++ may require `outfile.open(filename.c_str());`

Comment: Hi bro my datestring is Date object. So I need to convert this into a string first right? How can I do that?

Comment: @J.J There is no standard `Date` class to base the answer on, so the best I can do is offer generalities. Making a `datestring` should be a call to the `Date` class's `to_string` method, which you likely have to write. The guts of `to_string` could be as simple as `return std::to_string(year) + "-" + std::to_string(month) + "-" + std::to_string(day);` if `Date` is broken up into year, month, and day. If it isn't, breaking `Date` up depends in how you are storing the date information. If using a `time_t`, look at [`struct tm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/tm).

Answer (score 0):

And if you have numbers like integers or floats involved you can use stringstream to build up your datestring easily.